# how to extract ROI using stencil buffer

Tags: rendering, roi, stencil-buffer

What I want to do is that extracting where main avatar is using stencil buffer. 
I'm using `planeshift` which is opensource of 3D MMORPG game and this game 
uses `crystalspace` as rendering engine.

What I want to get is as below :

```
=====in stencil buffer=====
00000000000011000000000000
00000000000111100000000000
00000000001111110000000000
00000000001111110000000000
00000000000111100000000000
00000000000011000000000000
00000111111111111111100000
00000000000011000000000000
00000000000011000000000000
00000000000011000000000000
00000000000100100000000000
00000000001000010000000000
00000000010000001000000000
==========================
```

After rendering process, the stencil buffer should store the location of 
main avatar and it can be updated each frame.

But, I am not able to find where I should modify the code. 
Do you have any idea of this ?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? I don't think many will be able to answer your question otherwise.

Comment: I identified how to use stencil buffer, but I coudn't use it. I thought there exists the rendering process for each object. However, I couldn't figure out yet.